# Send PerformanceCounter to ApplicationInsights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to send some PerformanceCounters manually to ApplicationInsights.

I've tried posting directly to `https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track` with this body:

```
{
    "iKey": "xxxxxxx",
    "time": "2019-05-23T10:22:52.9586379Z",
    "name": "MetricData",
    "tags": {
        "ai.cloud.role": "My Test Role"
    },
    "data": {
        "baseType": "MetricData",
        "baseData": {
            "metrics": [
                {
                    "name": "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage",
                    "value": 0.5,
                    "count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This call ends up in `customMetrics` and I really want it to end up in `performanceCounters` so that I can use all the existing dashboards.

I've looked through github repos but can't find the place where is actually write ther perfconter to json.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: It has been public holiday in Denmark, but I'll look at it Monday 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: a quick test with following data via postman, and it works ok.

the data:

```
{
  "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.foo.PerformanceCounter",
  "time": "2019-05-28T08:22:20.6464765-07:00",
  "iKey": "xxxxx",
  "tags": { "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "1.2.0.5639" },
  "data": {
    "baseType": "PerformanceCounterData",
    "baseData": {
      "ver": 2,
      "categoryName": "Process",
      "counterName": "% Processor Time",
      "instanceName": "TestPerfCounters.vshost",
      "value": 20.0318031311035
    }
  }
}
```

in postman:

[image]

in azure portal -> app insights -> logs, I can find the data in **performanceCounters** table.

[image]

---

As per the last section of this [doc](http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/10/07/performance-counters-in-non-web-applications/), please try to change `"baseType" to "PerformanceCounterData"`.

Screenshot from the doc:

[image]

I did not have time to test it. But if any issues, please let me know.

Comment: performancecounterdata is deprecated in favor of regular metric. The post you referred is quite outdated. https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/DataContracts/PerformanceCounterTelemetry.cs#L12

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to make the metric appear in performancecounter table as opposed to customMetrics.

`metricTelemetry.Properties.Add("CustomPerfCounter", "true");`

If you can modify json payload also to do the same, you'll achieve what you want.